# Using menu inside a Badge without breaking line. From react-bootstrap framework

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

I need to display a menu inside a badge (from react-bootstrap), so I tried the following:

```
<div className="container">
     <Label className="nowrap"><span>Rule <OverflowMenu/></span></Label>
     <Badge variant="secondary" className="nowrap">Rule<OverflowMenu/></Badge>
</div>
```

and with this css:

```
.container {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  display: inline-flex;
}

.nowrap{
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*float: left;*/
}
```

But I'm getting the menu in a new line!

[image]

## Update

I think it's related to the OverflowMenu of react-carbon-components, when i used another element like Icon for example there is no new line.

When adding important to nowrap css attributes, I got something like this:

[image]

```
.nowrap{
  display: flex !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  /*float: left !important;*/
}
```

Comment: You might want to provide some details on what framework you are using to add these custom components.

Comment: I just mentioned react, my bad

Comment: Try to add `display: flex` to `.nowrap`

Comment: It didn't help  :~